# How to convert UUID value to string

Tags: java

I want to generate unique session id for my session. So i used UUID. Here what i did

```
if (session == null) {

    session = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("logedin", "0");

    if (!httpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie()) {

        UUID sessionID = UUID.randomUUID();

        Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", "sessionID");  //problem

}
```

The Cookie constructor accept two strings, how can i convert my UUID to string so it get the UUID value which is unique? 
Thanks

Comment: The servlet container has already tried to generate a cookie for you.  Overwriting it with another value will prevent the servlet container from finding your session.

Comment: HHmmm thanks. This is very very important point that i am not aware of. Thanks many. Actually what i was thinking is that. Session Tracking API generate the ID with the name `JSESSIONID`, so i thought that i just change the value . But you are saying that changing value disturb the default Session Tracking..... hhmm  ok i don't change the value but i want to ask that can i set setMaxAge() on the default JSESSIONID? Like get the default JSESSION cookie, set its maxAge and then use addCookie. Can i do that? Thanks

Comment: If you want to change the max-age in order to control when the session will expire, you should rather set the session-config>session-timeout element in the web.xml. Note that the JSESSIONID cookie does not necessarily contains _only_ the session ID.  On some containers, additional information is added after of before the session ID.  See [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/Dougclectica/entry)/websphere_session_ids22?lang=en for an example.  You are not supposed to alter the JSESSIONID cookie if you are doing regular stuff.

Comment: HHmm thanks.  Actually i have two kinds of users. One is normal and one is registered. If i set session-timeout in my DD. Then when session expires it will effect both users. when session expires then i throw message that your session has expired. Suppose user is normal user, he is not logged in, when session expires let say after 30 min, then he will see the message that your session has expired... Not right. I think i will have to set the session-timeout programatically like `session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30 min)`. When user logged in. What do you say? Is this approach right?..continue

Comment: But there is another problem with that, by default JSESSIONID has browser level cookie. If user is not logged in, and close the browser, then the condition `!httpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()` become true and he will see the message of session expiration. So i think i have to built another cookie, and set maxAge of that cokkie, and using that cookie i check whether there is timeout or not. What do you say about this?

Comment: sessionID.toString() will work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This will convert your uniques session id to string

```
String suuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `toString()` on all Java objects...

Comment: not on all Java objects yo get a desired behaviour. in this case, it works because `toString()` method is overridden: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString()

Comment: indeed, but it should be the first thing to try and ask if that one is not working, which is not the case here, as you can see from accepted answer...

Comment: Well I checked that in case of UUID, tostring() method will give you the same UUID in string format. So in this context it's true.